# calculate variance of all samples in r studio

Tags: r

I have 30 random samples taken from a data set. I need to calculate sample mean and sample variance for each sample, and arrange them in a table with  3 columns titled "sample", "mean", and "variance".

My dataset is:

```
lab6data <- c(2,5,4,6,7,8,4,5,9,7,3,4,7,12,4,10,9,7,8,11,8,
              6,13,9,6,7,4,5,2,3,10,13,4,12,9,6,7,3,4,2)
```

I made samples like:

```
observations <- matrix(lab6data, 30, 5)
```

and means for every sample separately by:

```
means <- rowMeans(observations)
```

Can you please help me to find the variance for every sample separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to calculate each column's sample deviation in data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276711/i-want-to-calculate-each-columns-sample-deviation-in-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the variance per row using `apply`:

```
apply(observations, 1, var)
```

Or use `rowVars` from the `matrixStats` package.

Note that `matrixStats::rowVars` will be <strike>slightly</strike> *much* faster (see @HenrikB's comment below) than `apply(..., 1, var)`, in the same way that `rowMeans` is faster than `apply(..., 1, mean)`.

Comment: thankyou so much for your quick response. Is there any way to get variance of all samples at once and add them to a table

Comment: @SadieKelsey *"Is there any way to get variance of all samples at once and add them to a table"* I'm not sure I understand. `apply(observations, 1, var)` will return a vector of the same length as `nrow(observations)`. You could store this vector as a new column (e.g. `observations$rowVar = apply(observations, 1, var)`), but in my opinion it's best to keep data and summary statistics in separate objects/tables.

Comment: i tried using Variance <- rowVars(observations)   
but it says 
Error in rowVars(observations) : could not find function "rowVars"

Comment: @SadieKelsey You need to install the `matrixStats` package first; e.g. do `install.packages("matrixStats")`.

Comment: I installed it as you said. It was installed successfully but still it says theirs no function called rowVars. in the drop down list that appear when i type also not having rowVars as suggestion.

Comment: Did you *load* the library? `library(matrixStats)`?

Comment: It worked after loading library.. also other way also worked. thanks for the Great help.

Comment: You're very welcome @SadieKelsey; please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: "I assume matrixStats::rowVars will be slightly faster than apply(..., 1, var)": it's actually **much** faster, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/wiki/colRowVars.  Same for `rowMeans()`, `.rowMeans()`, `matrixStats::rowMeans2()`, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/wiki/colRowMeans2

Comment: Thanks a lot @HenrikB, I've made an edit to my post to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap` to apply the function on each row of the `data.frame`

```
library(purrr)
varS <- pmap_dbl(as.data.frame(observations), ~ var(c(...)))
cbind(observations, varS)
```

#### data

```
observations <- matrix(lab6data, 10, 4)
```

Comment: Ill try to work on this way too thanks for the help. It was very useful.